# Where is the actual admin password located?

Tags: password

I'm just curious because I know the configuration for the password is located in `/etc/passwd`, but in the document I don't see my actual password anywhere, obviously for security reasons. I opened `passwd-` with `less` in the terminal and it can't be found there either.

How does Ubuntu know and read the password you give it?

Answer (score 3):

The password is not in /etc/password file in Unix systems ... some decades ago :)

The same policy is applied in Linux (Ubuntu too). Your passwords are encrypted in /etc/shadow file, and you need to be root to read the file. The passwords in /etc/shadow are *hashed* and this is an one-way operation. Ok, you will need (1) the string used for *hash* operation and (2) the *hash* algorithm used, and you can *will try* decrypt the /etc/shadow file (and remember, you will need root permissions for read this file).

You can find more details in this answer:

[How to decode the hash password in ./etc/shadow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383057/how-to-decode-the-hash-password-in-etc-shadow)

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are stored in `/etc/shadow`. They are encrypted. Integrity of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` can be verified via pwck command:

```
pwck -r /etc/passwd
pwck -r /etc/shadow
```

Passwords were once storred in `/etc/passwd`, but then they were moved to `/etc/shadow` to restrict access – while `/etc/passwd` can be read by any user, `/etc/shadow` is accessible only by root by default.