# Where to find password for users created in Ubuntu (16.04)

Tags: users

I'm new to Ubuntu. I have made two ordinary users on my Ubuntu and provided them with the same password.

Now I want to check if the passwords are similar but I don't know where to look for or what command to write in a terminal. Where do I find `/etc/password` ?.

Comment: User passwords are encrypted, you can not just "find" them. Also, what an annoying use of bold.

Answer (score 13):

There are two main files related to system user authentication: `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. The actual user's passwords are stored as [*hashed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) version in the `shadow` file. They are hashed by the [`crypt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/shadow.5.html) function. It is not possible to *"decrypt"* any password from the `shadow` file, because *hashing* is one way mechanism.

Most simply: When the user enters а password, it is processed and compared to the hashed password stored in the `shadow` file. But when one try to *"decrypt"* a password from the `shadow` file - there are over than thousands possible results.

Relevant questions:

- [How to decode the hash password in /etc/shadow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/383057/how-to-decode-the-hash-password-in-etc-shadow)
- [Change password on root user and user account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423942/change-password-on-root-user-and-user-account)

---

> **`/etc/passwd`** contains one line for each user account, with seven fields delimited by colons (`:`).
>
> These fields are: **1.** login name; **2.** *optional encrypted password*; **3.**
>   UID; **4.** GID; **5.** user name or comment field; **6.** user home
>   directory; **7.** optional user command interpreter.
>
> The encrypted password field may be blank, in which case no password
>   is required... However, some
>   applications which read the `/etc/passwd` file may decide not to
>   permit any access at all if the password field is blank.
>
> *If the password field is a lower-case `x`, then the encrypted password is actually stored in the `shadow` file instead*; there must
>   be a corresponding line in the `/etc/shadow` file, or else the user
>   account is invalid. If the password field is any other string, then it
>   will be treated as an encrypted password, as specified by [`crypt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/shadow.5.html). (source: [`man passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/passwd.5.html))

> **`/etc/shadow`** - shadowed password file - is a file which contains the password information for the system's accounts and optional aging
>   information. Each line of this file contains 9 fields, separated by colons (`:`).
>
> The fields are: **1.** login name; **2.** *encrypted password
>   - refer to [`crypt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/shadow.5.html) for details on how this string is interpreted*; **3.** date of last password change; **4.** min password age; **5.** max password age; **6.** password warning period; **7.** password inactivity period; **8.** account expiration date; **9.**
>   reserved field. (source: [`man shadow`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/shadow.5.html)).